# Two hyperbolas $ y_1 = \dfrac{k_1}{x} $ and $ y_2 = \dfrac{ k_2}{x} $ $ (k_1, k_2> 0) $ intersets a circle which touch the X-axis

Tags: contest-math, analytic-geometry, circles

> The circle whose center is located in the first coordinate quarter
> touches the $ Ox $ axis at the $ M $ point, intersects two hyperbolas
> $ y_1 = \dfrac{k_1}{x} $ and $ y_2 = \dfrac{ k_2}{x} $ $ (k_1, k_2> 0) $
> at the points $ A $ and $ B $ such that the line $ AB $ passes through
> the origin $ O $. It is known that $ \dfrac {4} {k_1} + \dfrac {1}{k_2} = 4 $. Find the smallest possible length of the $ OM $ segment.
> In response, write down the square of the length of the segment $ OM$.

[image]

I know if a circle equation is $(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = a^2$ , when it touches x-axis then, $k = a$ and so the equation will be $(x - h)^2 + (y - a)^2 = a^2 => x^2 + y^2 - 2hx - 2ay + h^2 = 0$.
The length of $OM$ will be $h$. The equation of $AB$ will be in $y = mx$ form.

Now, from $ y_1 = \dfrac{k_1}{x_1} $ and $ y_2 = \dfrac{ k_2}{x_2} $ $ (k_1, k_2> 0) $ , if we will $\dfrac{1}{y_1} + \dfrac{1}{y_2} = \dfrac{x_1}{k_1} + \dfrac{x_2}{k_2} = p  $ and comparing it with $ \dfrac {4} {k_1} + \dfrac {1}{k_2} = 4 $ we get $x_1 = 4; x_2 = 1; p = 4 $.

I can't get the idea to proceed further. Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $y=mx$ as the equation of the line $OA$ and find the coordinates of $A$ and $B$

$$B=\left\{\frac{k_1}{\sqrt{k_1 m}},\sqrt{k_1 m}\right\};A=\left\{\frac{k_2}{\sqrt{k_2 m}},\sqrt{k_2 m}\right\}$$

We have
$$OA^2=k_2 m+\frac{k_2}{m};\;OB^2=k_1 m+\frac{k_1}{m}$$

Now apply the theorem which states that $OM^2=OB\cdot OA$

$$OM^2=f(m)=\sqrt{k_1 m+\frac{k_1}{m}} \sqrt{k_2 m+\frac{k_2}{m}}$$

and set derivative equal to zero to find extrema.

$$f'(m)=\frac{k_1 k_2 \left(m^4-1\right)}{m^3 \sqrt{k_1 \left(m+\frac{1}{m}\right)} \sqrt{k_2 \left(m+\frac{1}{m}\right)}}$$

$f'(m)=0\to m=1$ since $m=-1$ gives a line crossing the second and fourth quadrant.

Since $f'(m)>0$ for $m>1$ we can conclude that $m=1$ is a minimum

$$OM^2=2 \sqrt{k_1k_2}$$

knowing that $\frac{4}{k_1}+\frac{1}{k_2}=4$ we can conclude that the minimum for $OM^2$ is
$$OM^2=\frac{k_1}{\sqrt{k_1-1}}$$

---

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Are  $k_1,k_2$  evaluated?